# Changing airport in Tokyo

Tags: japan, airport-transfer

I am planning to travel from Hong Kong to the US with an Indian passport. I have a US visa. I don't have a Japanese visa. The most convenient flight will have a long layover (almost 24 hours) in Japan with an airport change (HND to NRT). I would really like to maybe take a cab ride through Japan at most or just switch airports at least. Will not having a Japanese visa interfere with the airport switch?

And how hard would it be to get a 24 hour transit visa?

Edit: This trip will be in early August. Not sure if the covid situation is going to be as bad as it is now.

Comment: Surely there are direct HK-US flights you could take?  In these times it's wise to avoid transfers via other countries if at all possible.

Comment: Will you be staying in HK at least 14 days before departure?

Comment: @lambshaanxy, I figured this would be a cool way to get a quick view of Japan. Plus, the other flights are a little more expensive. No. I will be there for three days.

Comment: Japan has a loooooong list of countries which will prevent you from entering Japan if you were there at any time in the previous 14 days. So things may depend a lot on where you will have been before that trip. If that includes India, at this time you won’t be allowed in Japan.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks. I'd appreciate your source of info to use in the future.

Comment: The current list is [here](http://www.moj.go.jp/isa/content/001338898.pdf) Not sure if updates will be at the same address. I found it linked from [here](http://www.moj.go.jp/isa/hisho06_00099.html) (2nd link), itself linked from [here](https://www.isa.go.jp/en/nyuukokukanri01_00151.html) (2nd link), itself linked from [here](https://www.isa.go.jp/en/covid-19_index.html).

Comment: Apropos of your edit: the covid situation in August may well be no better or even worse than it is now. That may be unlikely in your view...but we won't actually know until we get there.

Comment: Sounds fair. I guess I'll skip Japan altogether. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the current time, what you're suggesting is not possible.

You will not be granted access to enter the country. Your chances of being issued with a visa for the purpose is very simply non-existent.

Even if you were somehow able to enter the country, you would not be allowed use public transport (including taxis) to transit between the two airports.

Comment: Mmmm... I believe Hong Kong is not on the current very long list of countries the visitors of which are not allowed into Japan at this time, though the information I found is not very consistent.

Comment: They have an Indian passport, not a Hong Kong passport.

Comment: @Avery Like most other countries, I believe the rules are based on where they were in the past 14 days, not their nationality: http://www.moj.go.jp/isa/content/001338898.pdf. They would need a transit visa, though. Whether such a visa would be granted nowadays is a good question. I'd recommend calling the Japan visa information hotline in India listed here: https://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/Visa.html -> +91-(0)11-7127-9532

Comment: @jcaron, although I am an Indian citizen, I stay in the US. I will be traveling in August which is quite a few months away. I will be fully vaccinated by then, if that makes any difference.